# Merge 2 nested arrays in one with multiple values

Tags: php

I have 2 nested arrays like this

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "id" => 6
  ],
  1 => array:1 [
    "id" => 4
  ]
]

array:1 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "id" => 509
  ],
  1 => array:1 [
    "id" => 256
  ]
]
```

I'm trying to merge this to arrays to have something like this

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "ssh_id" => 6
    "d_id"   => 509
  ],
  1 => array:1 [
    "ssh_id" => 4
    "d_id"   => 256
  ]
]
```

I tried `array_merge` functions from PHP, but I don't get the result I want. Is this possible?

Comment: Both arrays always have equal data or it contains variable data

Comment: Both arrays have equal number of datas

Comment: Then the solution given by @Aju John will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `for` loop also.

```
$final = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++){
    $final[] = array("ssh_id" => $arr1[$i]['id'], "d_id" => $arr2[$i]['id']);
}
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ssh_id] => 6
            [d_id] => 509
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ssh_id] => 4
            [d_id] => 256
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3):

To make it simple, I tried with looping:

```
$arr1 = array(
            array("id"=>6),
            array("id"=>"4")
    );
$arr2 = array(
            array("id"=>509),
            array("id"=>256)
    );

$result = array();
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$a) {
    $result[$k] = array("ssh_id"=>$a['id'], "d_id" => $arr2[$k]['id']);
}
```