# merge sub array into main array

Tags: php, arrays

how do i merge sub array into main array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [FirmId] => 1
            [PartyName] => abc medicals
            [PartyCode] => P001
            [SalesmanName] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [FirmId] => 2
            [PartyName] => xyz medicals
            [PartyCode] => P001
            [SalesmanName] => 
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SalesmanName] => abc
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [SalesmanName] => xyz
        )

)
```

**Output should be :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [FirmId] => 1
            [PartyName] => abc medicals
            [PartyCode] => P001
            [SalesmanName] => abc
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [FirmId] => 2
            [PartyName] => xyz medicals
            [PartyCode] => P001
            [SalesmanName] => xyz
        )

)
```

I tried **array_merge($arr1,$arr2);** but output was not as expected.
[Merge 2 nested arrays in one with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067643/merge-2-nested-arrays-in-one-with-multiple-values)
This solution is too expensive, actually my first array has 30 columns but i mentioned only 4 to simplify my question. 
Actually second array is a sliced part of main array need to merge it.

Comment: Assuming occurance [0] in both arrays point to the correct other array, did you try a simple foreach loop?

Comment: I was about to write an example using a couple `for` loops, but it is closed and truly IS a close match to the duplicate

Comment: I did using for loop but it is too expensive solution to loop again whole array

Comment: there must be any simple way to do that.

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

you want to use `array_merge_recursive()`

Comment: Without a simple demonstration this is really just a comment

Comment: array_merge_recursive() is also not working